# Find lines covering points on 2D space

Tags: python, c#, algorithm, line, mathematical-optimization

I have a list of points x,y. Mission is to find the smallest number of lines that goes through them (but one line goes by **maximum 5 points**). The other thing is that it doesn't have to be exact line, Line is good even if it's not exactly on the point, can be 8x or|and 8y away from point.
Any help would be awesome.

```
[20,50],
[15,37],
[29,77],
[24,120],
[12,60],
[27,53],
[11,24],
[53,34],
[43,23]
```

I have to do it in C# or Python. The points can be diffrent they will be random.

Comment: Could you please rephrase the condition *"line is on point if it's close max 8 points from it."*? It's a bit unclear what "8 points from it" means.

Comment: Line is good even if it's not exactly on the point, can be 8x or|and 8y away from point.

Comment: If points are [10,10] [23,17] [30,30] the middle point is also "covered" by line that goes 10,10 to 30,30, the line "thickness" is 8 points from middle. Sorry for poorly explanation, english isn't my main language

Comment: Can you show us your code so far?

Comment: The code is just a generator and drawer of points on 2d box. I stuck on [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-k-closest-points-to-the-origin/) that I used to make line through two points.

Comment: If you have six points in a row (e.g., [0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 0], [4, 0], [5, 0]) is there no solution, or can we use two lines (which inevitably happen to cover the other points)?

Comment: Then twe two lines, one line stops when it's full of 5 points. Then the next one start

Comment: Can be solved in two steps. 1) Generate a list of possible lines, and from those create sets of points. 2) Solve the [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem).

The set cover problem is NP-hard, but ironically the easy part of this problem (since it has been thoroughly studied, and a variety of solution strategies are known).

Comment: Generating the list of possible lines is difficult, since computers are horrible at 2D spatial recognition problems. One simplification you can make is to only consider lines that go through two of the input points. Then find any other points that are within 8 units of that line. So if you have A and B as the two points forming the line, and C,D,E,F are close to the line, then there are [(4 choose 3) = 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) sets of points: (ABCDE, ABCDF, ABCEF, ABDEF).

Comment: @user3386109 Only considering lines that go through two of the input points is a great simplification, but it's easy to construct an example in which it would miss an optimal solution (where there exists a line that's close enough to 5 points, but none of the lines that go through two points are close enough to those five points)

Comment: @Stef Yes, and that's something that OP needs to sort out. I think it's best to let the OP do at least a little bit of work on their own.